# Update UserDefaults changes in real time

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

When the user taps on the button, it changes the UserDefaults to change the background color enabling the Dark Mode. But I want that when the user taps on my button, the color change transitions happen in real time, like what the Twitter app does,  without the necessity of reopening the app every time. Is there any way that I can do that?

This is the code of the button:

```
@IBAction func changeState(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")

    if isDarkMode == true {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "isDarkMode")  // Set the state
    }else{
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isDarkMode")  // Set the state
    }
}
```

And this is the code that I use to update the color of the UI:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")  // Retrieve the state

    if isDarkMode == false{
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]//user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default //user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white //user global variable
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
        appVersionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        lightModeLabel.isHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        settingsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        darkModeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "darkModeDisableButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

    }else{

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]//user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default //user global variable
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white //user global variable
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        appVersionLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        darkModeLabel.isHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        settingsView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 35/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)


        darkModeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "darkModeEnableButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    }
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with UserDefaults. You need to write code to update your UI immediately based on the updated preference.

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but your `if/else` in `changeState` can be replaced with one line: `UserDefaults.standard.set(!isDarkMode, forKey: "isDarkMode")`

Comment: Also unrelated, but would highly recommend you look into extensions around your navbar and possibly uilabel to clean up this code. Would really improve readability and streamline this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isolate the theming code in a function :

```
func changeMode(mode: Bool) {
    let bar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
    if mode == false {
        bar?.isTranslucent = false
        bar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]//user global variable
        bar?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default //user global variable
        bar?.tintColor = UIColor.white //user global variable
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .default
        appVersionLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        lightModeLabel.isHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        settingsView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        darkModeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "darkModeDisableButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)

    } else {

        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        bar?.isTranslucent = false
        bar?.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]//user global variable
        bar?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default //user global variable
        bar?.tintColor = UIColor.white //user global variable
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        appVersionLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
        darkModeLabel.isHidden = true
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
        settingsView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 35/255, green: 35/255, blue: 35/255, alpha: 1)

        darkModeButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "darkModeEnableButton")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Your `viewDidLoad()` would look like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")  // Retrieve the state
    changeMode(mode: isDarkMode)
}
```

And your IBAction :

```
@IBAction func changeState(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let isDarkMode = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isDarkMode")
    //Pointed out by rmaddy
    UserDefaults.standard.set(!isDarkMode, forKey: "isDarkMode")
    changeMode(mode: !isDarkMode)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect. And if I want to also change the background color behind this view? This is the case: https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n983zd5bimvs6e/Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20-%20iPhone%20X%20-%202018-09-11%20at%2021.23.09.png?dl=0

Comment: You can style your views in `changeMode(mode: Bool)` as you like, for example `yourView.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow`...

Comment: It works for the settings page, but it does not work for me when changing the color of the background view

Comment: You'll have to check if the `isDarkMode` variable in the other view controllers too.

Comment: Yes, the code is pretty much the same, I also tried to change the viewDidLoad() with something like viewDidAppear(), but nothing